How to get the Kubernetes node count using Prometheus which the specific Pod name is running
I want to get the Kubernetes node count which the pods name like "distributed-jmeter-slave.*" from Prometheus using PromQL for the given time range
Note :- I have integrated the Prometheus and I want to display the output in the Grafana Dashboard as a number
Tried out below query but it seems the output is incorrect
sum(sum(count_over_time(kube_pod_created{pod=~"distributed-jmeter-slave.*"}[5m])) by (kubernetes_node)) by (time)

Alternatively, the query is incorrect.sum(...) by (time) would summarize an instant vector by a label time. It's unlikely (not impossible) that the instant vector contains a label time. So this statement is possibly redundant.

The inner sum(...) by (kubernetes_node) would summarize an instant vector by a label kubernetes_node. This label is more likely (though I don't see it listed against the definition of these metrics). However, it appears to do the opposite to what you want. You want to summarize regardless of the node ("across nodes") and so you'd want the equivalent of sum(...) without(kubernetes_node)

kube_pod_created is a timestamp (according to the definition). count_over_time(kube_pod_created{}[5m]) counts the number of measurements (i.e. number of timestamps) within the last 5 minutes.

One challenge with helping with PromQL is being able to infer the time series in question. Could you provide a synopsis of the time series with which you're working (including labels) and a desired outcome and we'll try to help.

I found a query and seems it's working
count(irate(kube_pod_created{pod=~"<pod_name>."}[30d]))
e.g:
count(irate(kube_pod_created{pod=~"distributed-jmeter-slave."}[30d]))
